# Conditional Formatting of cells with color based on yes no values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, background-color, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet full of IP addresses ('IP LIST').  Within that workbook, I have a second spreadsheet representative of the section of IP addresses which belong to the printers ('Printers') within the larger section of the IP addresses.  I have identified which IP addresses are active and which are offline on 'IP LIST'. With this information, I would like to do two things:

1. Color code via Conditional Formatting the IP addresses on 'IP LIST' those IP's which are offline vs online.
2. Copy this formatting to the 'Printers' worksheet within the workbook, so that upon the updating of the 'IP LIST' Worksheet, both sheets are updated in one fell swoop.

I have spent my morning trying to figure out how to accomplish this.  I have done it before, however, it was a year and a half ago.  If I remember correctly, I believe I used a Yes/No type formatting, but I do not remember the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your comprehensive list of IP addresses is in A1:A100 and ColumnB has `active` and `offline` and blanks to suit then two rules set with formulae as below should highlight the `IP LIST` sheet:

[image: SO12676460 example]

The easiest way to arrange for live updating in a different sheet in the same workbook may be to recreate the `Printers` list from `IP LIST` with inclusion of ColumnB (for the formatting) and delete any non-printers. This though would required ColumnB cells in `Printers` to be linked to the corresponding cells in `IP LIST`.

An alternative, still requiring cell linking, would be merely to repeat the CF rules for the `Printers` sheet.